# ExtJS FormPanel with image thumbnail next to file upload

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a FormPanel which basically consists of a FileUpload. What I want to do is the following: when editing, show a thumbnail of the already uploaded image to the right of the file upload field. My items look like this:

```
items = [
{
    allowBlank: false,
    fieldLabel: 'Icon',
    hidden: true,
    name: 'Icon',
    ref: 'IconField',
    xtype: 'Ext.ux.form.FileUploadField'
},
{
    ref: 'PreviewImage',
};
```

I need to do two things:

- Load the image inside the 'PreviewImage' component, I would do this via something like `this['PreviewImage'].update('<img src="image.png" />');` Is this the best way to do it?
- Get the image to float to the right of the upload field. I'm not sure on the best way to do this? I've thought of putting both elements in a Panel, but again, I don't know what the best way is to do this?

Any ideas are very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide whether you want to support old browsers or not.

If you do, you have to submit the form to the server (which uploads the image), and have the server return the url of the image, and then set this as the src of the image. This is done via a hidden IFrame, so the page is not refreshed.

The modern, HTML5 way would be to use the FileReader api to read the image before it's uploaded and set it as the src of the image (as a dataurl), and then upload it using XmlHttpRequest Level 2 . Use the FormData class.

To get the image beside the filefield, you could use a column or hbox layout. That does the floating for you.